# Средства для измерения времени выполнения кода

Tags: время, c++

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие-нибудь библиотеки для измерения времени выполнения участка кода на С++.

Answer (score 4):

Под Windows можно использовать QueryPerformanceCounter и QueryFrequencyCounter. Если необязательно нужен самый точный таймер, то можно использовать GetTickCount.

Для измерения времени выполнения участка кода, сохраняй время до него и вычитай его из времени, полученном сразу после выполнения кода. Чтобы точнее вычислить время, желательно повторить код в цикле несколько раз, и результат поделить на это количество.

Answer (score 3):

Я меряю в миллисекундах. IMHO в реальности более мелким единицам доверять (при замерах производительности) нельзя.

```
/*
  avp

  время в миллисекундах
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

long long
mtime()
{
  struct timeval t;

  gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
  long long mt = (long long)t.tv_sec * 1000 + t.tv_usec / 1000;
  return mt;
}
```

Очень просто, работает и в Windows (использую MinGW) и в Linux.

Answer (score 2):

[time.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time/) - подключив библиотеку можно воспользоваться функцией получения времени time() - получить время перед выполнением блока кода, и после. Время выполнения блока, будет разницей полученных времен.

Answer (score 2):

достал из своих старых исходников такое решение без использования буст. немного длинно прошу извинить

**заголовок *profiler.h***

```
#ifndef __unix
    #include <windows.h>
#endif

typedef unsigned __int64    uint64_t;
typedef unsigned int        uint32_t;
typedef unsigned short      uint16_t;
typedef unsigned char       uint8_t;

typedef __int64             int64_t;
typedef signed int          int32_t;
typedef signed short        int16_t;
typedef signed char         int8_t;

union uint64x32_t {
    uint64_t    m_ui64;
    struct ui32 {
        uint32_t    m_uiLow;
        uint32_t    m_uiHigh;
    }   m_ui32;
};

#define PROFILE_CALIBRATE   500 //  2 секунды

namespace Profiler {
    // Класс, который снимает время выполнения участка кода
    class CPU {     
        static int  m_iFrequency;               // частота процессора (КГц)

        uint64x32_t m_uiLastTick;               // последний зарегстрированный отсчет
        uint32_t    m_uiCountScale;             // кол-во проверок
        uint64_t    m_uiAccumulateTicks;        // суммарное кол-во тиков процессорного времени
        uint64_t    m_uiMinDelta, m_uiMaxDelta; // минимальный и максимальные отрезки

        static void     Calibrate(int iProfilerCalibrate);
    public:
        CPU(int iProfilerCalibrate = PROFILE_CALIBRATE);
        virtual ~CPU();

        void    Reset();
        void    CheckIn();
        void    CheckOut();

        inline uint32_t     GetScaleCount(){return m_uiCountScale;}
        inline uint64_t     GetAccumulateTicks(){return m_uiAccumulateTicks;}

        double      GetAverageTime(){return ((double)m_uiAccumulateTicks)/(m_uiCountScale*m_iFrequency);}
    };

    class ShotCPU : public CPU { 
    public:
        ShotCPU(int iProfilerCalibrate = PROFILE_CALIBRATE):
            CPU(iProfilerCalibrate) {
            CheckIn();
        }

        virtual ~ShotCPU(){
            CheckOut();
            fprintf(stdout, "\t%f", GetAverageTime());
        }
    };
}

#define SHOT_PROFILER_CPU       Profiler::ShotCPU       __s__p__
```

**реализация *profiler.cpp***

```
using namespace Profiler;

#ifdef UNIX
#include <unistd.h>

#define _rdtsc_(val) asm volatile ("rdtsc" : "=A" (val))
#else
#define rdtsc __asm _emit 0x0f __asm _emit 0x31
#endif

int CPU::m_iFrequency = 0;

CPU::CPU(int iProfilerCalibrate){
    Reset();

    if(iProfilerCalibrate!=0 && m_iFrequency==0)
        Calibrate(iProfilerCalibrate);
}

CPU::~CPU() {
}

void CPU::Calibrate(int iProfilerCalibrate){
    uint64x32_t FirstTick,LastTick;

    if(iProfilerCalibrate!=0){
#ifdef UNIX
        _rdtsc_(FirstTick.m_ui64);
        usleep(iProfilerCalibrate*1000);
        _rdtsc_(LastTick.m_ui64);
#else
        rdtsc;
        __asm mov  FirstTick.m_ui32.m_uiLow,eax
        __asm mov  FirstTick.m_ui32.m_uiHigh,edx

        Sleep(iProfilerCalibrate);

        rdtsc;
        __asm mov  LastTick.m_ui32.m_uiLow,eax
        __asm mov  LastTick.m_ui32.m_uiHigh,edx
#endif
        m_iFrequency = (int)((LastTick.m_ui64 - FirstTick.m_ui64)/iProfilerCalibrate);
    }
}

void CPU::Reset(){
    m_uiCountScale      = 0;
    m_uiAccumulateTicks = 0;
    m_uiMinDelta        = 0;
    m_uiMaxDelta        = 0;
}

void CPU::CheckIn(){
    uint64x32_t uiCurrentTick;
#ifdef UNIX
    _rdtsc_(uiCurrentTick.m_ui64);
#else
    rdtsc;
    __asm mov  uiCurrentTick.m_ui32.m_uiLow,eax
    __asm mov  uiCurrentTick.m_ui32.m_uiHigh,edx
#endif
    m_uiLastTick.m_ui64 = uiCurrentTick.m_ui64;
}

void CPU::CheckOut(){
    uint64x32_t uiCurrentTick;
#ifdef UNIX
    _rdtsc_(uiCurrentTick.m_ui64);
#else
    rdtsc;
    __asm mov  uiCurrentTick.m_ui32.m_uiLow,eax
    __asm mov  uiCurrentTick.m_ui32.m_uiHigh,edx
#endif
    uiCurrentTick.m_ui64 -= m_uiLastTick.m_ui64;
    m_uiCountScale++;
    m_uiAccumulateTicks += uiCurrentTick.m_ui64;

    m_uiMinDelta = m_uiMinDelta==0?uiCurrentTick.m_ui64:min(m_uiMinDelta,uiCurrentTick.m_ui64);
    m_uiMaxDelta = m_uiMaxDelta==0?uiCurrentTick.m_ui64:max(m_uiMaxDelta,uiCurrentTick.m_ui64);
}
```

самое простое использование  - вставить SHOT_PROFILER_CPU в начало блока, скорость выполнения которого нужно замерить. 
    {
       SHOT_PROFILER_CPU;
    // Какой то код
    }

Answer (score 2):

С появлением C++11, появились дополнительные **кроссплатформенные** решения по измерению скорости выполнения кода стандартными средствами. В С++11 имеется библиотека времени [chrono](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/).

В мире компьютера существует два типа часов:

- *REALTIME*(измеряет реальное время в системе)
- *MONOTONIC*(измеряет время начиная с некоторого времени в прошлом и всегда увеличивается)

Вкратце, чтобы показать разницу между типами: если взять и перевести в системе часы назад, то значение *MONOTONIC* часов по-прежнему будет увеличиваться, а значение *REALTIME* часов станут меньше, так как системные часы переведены назад.
Чем отличаются эти два типа часов более подробно рассказано в [английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523442/difference-between-clock-realtime-and-clock-monotonic). 
Для измерения времени выполнения кода **предпочтительнее** использовать **MONOTONIC** часы.

В библиотеке chrono классом, реализующего *MONOTONIC* часы, является класс [steady_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock). Он гарантирует реальное измерение времени с максимально высокой точностью. С помощью него измерить разницу можно очень просто

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::cout << "Diff(ms) = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Diff(ns) = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds> (end - begin).count() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    long t1 = clock();
    long t2 = clock();
    // какой-то код
    cout << t2 - t1 << endl; // это измерит время в миллисекундах
    // без загрузки выдаст 0
}
```

Ещё очень часто удобно просто компилировать с опцией `-fopenmp (g++ -fopenmp ...)`, подключать `omp.h` и использовать `double omp_get_wtime()`, которая возвращает время в секундах, но имеет тип `double`, т.е. покажет затраченное время, как, например, `12.3452` (`12,3452` секунды):

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
    #include <omp.h>
#endif

int main() {
#ifdef _OPENMP
    double t1 = omp_get_wtime();
    // ...
    double t2 = omp_get_wtime();
#endif
}
```

Удобно в связи с форматом (double) и тем, что почти все имеют поддержку openmp (gcc, компилятор в Microsoft Visual Studio, насколько я знаю, тоже, и др).

Comment: Для целей отладки подключать OpenMP еще куда ни шло. Но для релиза тянуть такую тяжелую библиотеку ради одной функции - не надо.

Comment: Согласен, это несерьёзно. Но просто "для дома" это удобный вариант. Естественно уже без условных компиляций.

Comment: У меня с time.h выводит 0.

Comment: Первый код? Ну если никакой загрузки нет, то да - проходит менее одной миллисекунды. Если там написать `sleep(1)` или `Sleep(1000)` (для Windows), то напишет 1000, если как-то ещё загрузить или потянуть время, напишет не 0.

Comment: Вот такой код.

 #include <iostream>
 #include <time.h>

 using namespace std;

 typedef unsigned short uShort;

 int main()
 {

     uShort i = 100;
     uShort a = 100;

     clock_t t1 = clock();

     while (true) {

  ++a;
  ++i;

  if (a + i == 1000)
      break;

     }

     clock_t t2 = clock();
     cout << t2 - t1;

     return 0;
 }

Comment: Чтобы проверить время работы какого-то участка, надо его проитерировать n-ное количество раз. И потом вычислить среднее.

Comment: Это просто очень "лёгкий" код... 800 раз сделать integer++ и 400 раз сделать (int + int) == 1000 - это явно меньше, чем на одну миллисекунду.

Comment: Да, но при таком коде никак не должно выводить 0.

Comment: @username76, 1000 итераций Вашего while(true) { ... } займут несколько **МИКРОсекунд** на любой современной PC.

Comment: @username76, то что меньше половины миллисекунды по-любому будет оценено как ноль.

Comment: Теперь проблема выводит статично 94, в любой программе.

Comment: Всё правильно этот код выводит... Он выводит миллисекунды, что не так? У меня всё как по маслу, выводит как часы просто. Сначала трёхзначные, потом 1xxx, потом 2xxx, всё норм.

Comment: @ivkremer функция `double omp_get_wtime( );` возвращает время не в миллисекундах, а в секундах [ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/t3282fe5.aspx)

Comment: @golubtsoff большое спасибо, поправил.

Answer (score 1):

[boost::timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/timer/timer.htm)

> - **timer**: Измерение затраченного времени.
> - **progress_timer**: Измерение затраченного времени (с использованием таймера), воспроизведение при уничтожении.
> - **progress_display**: Отображение информации о прогрессе в направлении заданной цели.